Conditionally color dataframe cells in python terminal
I have a dataframe.
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Name": ['Alice','Bob', 'Sue','Joe','rose','cindy'],
    "Age": [11, 6, 3, 16, 21, 8],
    "Num": [2, 17, 12, 7, 22, 9],
    "Score": [3, 8, 13, 18, 3, 23],
    "Dep": [4, 19, 8, 11, 6, 20],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I want cells of column "Name" to be colored in python terminal which have "Age" greater than "Num"

Try to use ANSI escape codes.

any example of it

I was trying it with termcolor but didn't get the desired result

You could use termcolor and a condition:
# %pip install termcolor
import termcolor

out = (df.assign(Name=[termcolor.colored(n, 'red' if c else 'white')
                       for c, n in zip(df['Age'].gt(df['Num']), df['Name'])])
        # we also rename the column to ensure proper alignment
        .rename(columns={'Name': termcolor.colored('Name', 'white')})
      )

print(out)

Output:


You can do this with Jupyter. Define a function for the style:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Name": ['Alice','Bob', 'Sue','Joe','rose','cindy'],
    "Age": [11, 6, 3, 16, 21, 8],
    "Num": [2, 17, 12, 7, 22, 9],
    "Score": [3, 8, 13, 18, 3, 23],
    "Dep": [4, 19, 8, 11, 6, 20],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def colorize_columns(row):
    styles = [''] * len(row)  # Default (empty) style for all columns
    
    if row['Age'] > row['Num']:
        styles[0] = 'background-color: yellow'  # Apply yellow background to Name

    return styles

styled_df = df.style.apply(colorize_columns, axis=1)
styled_df

Output:

If you would like text color too, change to:
styles[0] = 'background-color: yellow; color: red'
Write the css to html:
styled_frame.to_html('test.html')
On terminal I think it‘s not easy, find one answer here
